# Transpose Columns in a single comma separated row conditionally

Tags: shell, awk, ksh

I have an input file that looks like this:

```
aaa 111    
aaa 222
aaa 333
bbb 444
bbb 555
```

I want to create a transposed output file that looks like this:

```
aaa 111,222,333
bbb 444,555
```

How can I do this using `awk`, `sed`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1]","$2:$2}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' file
aaa 111,222,333
bbb 444,555
```

And if your implementation of `awk` doesn't support the ternary operator then:

```
$ awk 'a[$1]{a[$1]=a[$1]","$2;next}{a[$1]=$2}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' file 
aaa 111,222,333
bbb 444,555
```

---

Your new file does not cause any problems for the script, what output are you getting? I suspect it's probably a line ending issue. Run `dos2unix file` to fix the line ending.

```
$ cat file
APM00065101435 189
APM00065101435 190
APM00065101435 191
APM00065101435 390
190104555 00C7
190104555 00D1
190104555 00E1
190104555 0454
190104555 0462

$ awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1]","$2:$2}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' file
APM00065101435 189,190,191,390
190104555 00C7,00D1,00E1,0454,0462
```

Comment: getting a syntax error.. not sure what I am doing wrong :         #cat testtr | awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1]","$2:$2}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}'
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1

Comment: No..i am on a Solaris 10 host using ksh

Comment: Its only usr/bin/awk. can we do this in perl ?

Comment: You have **old/broken** `awk` then, this version should not be used at all please use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead!

Comment: that version of awk worked ! but it worked only for decimal nos. i have hex numbers also in the list and it skipped them(0c7,0d1,0e1).. below is sample data:APM00065101435  189
APM00065101435  190
APM00065101435  191
APM00065101435  390
190104555       00C7
190104555       00D1
190104555       00E1
190104555       0454
190104555       0462

Comment: after dos2unix, it worked flawlessly ! Sorry about the unformatted text. And thanks a ton for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

---

I made a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17414805/2468910) for this and got a very good & useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17418598/2468910) from [potong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong):

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/^(([^ ]+ ).*)\n\2/\1,/;ta;P;D' file
```

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/^((\S+\s).*)\n\2/\1,/;ta;P;D' file
```

Comment: The commas are still missing.