# complex transposing of columns with pure sed

Tags: regex, sed, pattern-matching

I tried a couple of hours to find a **pure [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)** solution for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17384781/2468910) question. Obviously,  unfortunately I had not succeed. A really tricky question.

---

Examples (from the awk question):

- input:

```
aaa 111    
aaa 222
aaa 333
bbb 444
bbb 555
ccc 666
```

- output:

```
aaa 111,222,333
bbb 444,555
ccc 666
```

---

- input

```
APM00065101435 189
APM00065101435 190
APM00065101435 191
APM00065101435 390
190104555 00C7
190104555 00D1
190104555 00E1
190104555 0454
190104555 0462
APM00065101435 391
APM00065101435 392
```

- output

```
APM00065101435 189,190,191,390
190104555 00C7,00D1,00E1,0454,0462
APM00065101435 391,392
```

---

What have I tried? Some of my non working examples:

```
sed -nr '1{h;b};H;x;/(\S+).*\n\1.*\'/M{x;b};s/.*\'//m;s/\n\S*\s*/,/g;s/,$//;p' file
sed -nr '1{h;b};H;x;h;s/(\S+).*\n(\S+).*\'/\1\n\2/m;/(\S+)\n\1\'/M{$!b;g;bk};g;s/\n.*\'//m;:k;s/^\S+\s//2mg;s/\n/,/g;p;x;s/.*\n//;h;$l' file2
sed -nr 'H;g;s/(\S+)\s.*/\1/gm;/(\S+)\n\1\'/M{$!b;g;bk};g;1d;s/\n.*\'//m;:k;s/\n\S+\s/,/2g;s/\n//;p;g;s/\n.*(\n.*)$/\1/;h' file2
```

<sub>*Thanks for reading this.*</sub>

Comment: Ugh...this *might* be possible...but I'm certainly not going to try to waste my time figuring out if it is or not!  Why do you want a pure sed solution?  This problem is a snap for awk...why make life harder on yourself?

Comment: A solution for this in `awk` or `perl` will be more readable, maintainable and will make you dream of unicorns!! Just do it for unicorn man (or wait until [potong](http://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong) wakes up)!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/^(([^ ]+ ).*)\n\2/\1,/;ta;P;D' file
```

or if you prefer:

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/^((\S+\s).*)\n\2/\1,/;ta;P;D' file
```

This reads 2 lines into the pattern space, compares the beginning of each line and if they are the same replaces the beginning of the second line that matches the first with a comma and repeats. If the lines do not match it prints out the first line.

Comment: Thank you very much, potong. You helped me again. I am very much obliged to you, thanks. I would pay you a bounty if I could!